# Multi-site just separated content

Tags: 7, multi-sites

There is a lot of blog posts and tutorial about multi-site with content sharing.

But what about inverse of it? Multi-site with separated contents?

Exactly which tables should be shared?

here is my settings.php for sub-site:

```
$databases = array(
    'default' =>
    array(
        'default' =>
        array(
            'database' => 'xxx',
            'username' => 'xxx',
            'password' => 'xxx',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'port' => '',
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'prefix' => 'default_portal_',
            'prefix' => array(
                'default' => 'default_portal_',
                // Users
                'users' => '',
                'sessions' => '',
                'role' => '',
                'role_permission' => '',
                'authmap' => '',
                'blocked_ips' => '',

                // Blocks
                'block' => '',
                'block_custom' => '',
                'block_node_type' => '',
                'block_role' => '',

                // CKEditor
                'ckeditor_input_format' => '',
                'ckeditor_settings' => '',

                'comment_notify_user_settings' => '',

                // Configuration
                'date_formats' => '',
                'date_format_locale' => '',
                'date_format_type' => '',
                'field_config' => '',
                'field_config_instance' => '',
                'filter' => '',
                'filter_format' => '',
                'i18n_block_language' => '',
                'i18n_string' => '',
                'i18n_translation_set' => '',
                'image_effects' => '',
                'image_styles' => '',
                'languages' => '',
                'locales_source' => '',
                'locales_target' => '',
                'node_type' => '',
                'quicktabs' => '',
                'rdf_mapping' => '',

                // Support
                'support_assigned' => '',
                'support_client' => '',
                'support_priority' => '',
                'support_reference' => '',
                'support_states' => '',
                'support_ticket' => '',
                'support_ticket_comment' => '',

                // System
                'system' => '',
                'taxonomy_term_data' => '',
                'taxonomy_term_hierarchy' => '',
                'taxonomy_vocabulary' => '',
                'variable' => '',
                'variable_store' => '',

                // Views
                'views_display' => '',
                'views_view' => '',

                // WYSIWYG
                'wysiwyg' => '',
                'wysiwyg_user' => '',
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

**EDIT**

Above configuration works after cache clearing, but some tables should not shared: `variable` and `variable_store` because of site_title and site_slogan ...

**EDIT**

If I share `block` table, I should enable all themes in main site.

yet I have question to ensure which tables should share?

Comment: I need just one expert guy approves my `settings.php`

Answer (score 1):

Yes , this is good idea, in one of my past work we do something like this, dedicated  drupal core but with separate content .